# From one-line list to one element per line in python-mode

Tags: python, fill-paragraph

How do I turn a long one-line list, such as

```python
test_list = ['a0000000', 'b1111111', 'c2222222', 'd3333333', 'e4444444', 'f5555555', 'g6666666']
```

into a one element per line list:

```python
test_list = ['a0000000',
             'b1111111',
             'c2222222',
             'd3333333',
             'e4444444',
             'f5555555',
             'g6666666']
```

Or:

```python
test_list = [
    'a0000000',
    'b1111111',
    'c2222222',
    'd3333333',
    'e4444444',
    'f5555555',
    'g6666666',
]
```

With `fill-paragraph` long one-line lists are at least broken up into multiline lists:

```python
test_list = ['a0000000', 'b1111111', 'c2222222', 'd3333333',
             'e4444444', 'f5555555', 'g6666666' ]
```

But I would find a one element per line list in many cases more useful. Is anyone aware of such a elisp function (e.g. in elpy or anywhere else)?

Comment: `Black` formats it accordig to PEP guidlines. And I found most of the time, it does so with 1 value per line. The other possibility I see, is for you to try out macros. Do it one time with the first element, select the rest and set the cursor correctly for the second one. Then run `apply-macro-to-region-lines`. You will probably fail the first time, but it's a good way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a function to do what you want and bind it to a key sequence. The following will deal with the vast majority of cases, but it will fail if a list element contains the string ", ". It assumes that your cursor is at the beginning of the line in question (and leaves `point` unchanged), searches for the string ", " in the line and calls `newline` after each one (which deals intelligently with the space-to-newline conversion). It then calls `indent-region` between the original `point` and the final end-of-line, to reindent everything properly. It will also work on multi-line lists (e.g. the two-line list after `M-q`) although you will have to call it once on each line:

```el
(defun python-list-break-and-indent ()
  "Convert a single-line list into a block list, indented properly.
   ASSUMPTION: the only occurrences of the string \", \" are between
   list elements."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((beg (point)))
      (while (search-forward ", " (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point)) t)
        (newline))
      (end-of-line)
      (indent-region beg (point)))))

(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c b") #'python-list-break-and-indent)
```

I bound the function to `C-c b` because it was undefined in `python-mode-map` in my case, but you should check with `C-h c C-c b` in a python mode buffer and choose something else if it is taken (`C-c <letter>` keys are supposed to be reserved for users).

Comment: Thanks @NickD nice solution!

Comment: I realized that, for example, the ESS mode for R files overrides `fill-paragraph` with `ess-r--fill-paragraph`. This works even with commas in the string and at any point in the list. Unfortunately my knowledge of elisp is not good enough to understand what is done there. But anyways, NickD your solution is a good start, which already helps a lot ;)

Comment: `ess-r--fill-paragraph` is a function that's used to [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions) `fill-paragraph`: it basically deals with a few R-specific constructs (code comments, call arguments, continuations, roxy blocks - whatever they are) but in all other cases calls the original `fill-paragraph` function. It's a powerful method to customize a function that does *almost* what you want, amd make it do *exactly* what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the advice feature! Having a look at the ESS functions didn't bring me very far. Too little knowledge in elisp :/ But thanks for your answer :)